# Setting a data breakpoint on an element of a std::map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dictionary, breakpoints

I have a `std::map` which is a private member of a class. One of it's values is being changed (when it shouldn't) and I can't figure out where. Once the map is assembled, the element in question is always going to be the last, due to the nature of the keys being used.

I'm trying to set a data breakpoint on the last element (the sixth one to be precise) in Visual Studio 2010 but am having no luck. I've looked through the header of both `map` and `xtree` (its base) and can't find a suitable member to use.

Does anyone know how to set a data breakpoint on the value of an element in a `std::map`?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind would be a hardware breakpoint, but that would require you to know the address of that map once it's created or just declare it as `static`, both of which probably won't work in your case. I'm very curious about how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the debugger to browse through the map to the actual `.second` data member, and then tack an `&` in front of the expression it generated. Then put that address into the data breakpoint and see if you have better luck.